# Google AppEngine Python: sys.path discrepancy between dev_appserver and webapp2 handlers

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, webapp2

"import django" statement in one of my handlers was failing with ImportError.
When looking into this, I found that sys.path in dev_appserver.py and my handler is different.

Why the discrepancy?

What is the role of dev_appserver.py, especially relative to wsgi.py?
I understand that when a page request is being made, wsgi.py is called.

sys.path in dev_appserver.py includes django path but not the sys.path in my handler.

Comment: Are you adding the django library in `app.yaml`?  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27

Comment: You're only going to get into a world of pain if you start trying to work out how GAE handles paths. There's all sorts of really really deep ugly magic going on with imports deep in the bowels of the app engine libraries.

Comment: @GAEfan Yes, I have django added in app.yaml.

Thanks Daniel.